# BundleConfig.vb - VisualBasic.Net

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes.

Estoy comenzando un nuevo "Sitio Web", realizado en Visual Basic .NET.

Hace poco comencé a utilizar MVC (C#), y una característica que me pareció buena es la del "BundleConfig" que te permite agrupar diferentes script CSS y JS, para renderizar en la página.

Bien, logré hacer funcionar esta característica en mi solución Visual Basic, y funciona sin problemas, cuando pruebo el aplicativo.

**El inconveniente lo tengo a la hora de utilizar el intellisense de las clases CSS.**

Si agrego los script de la manera tradicional:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/styles.css" />
```

el intellisense funciona sin problemas y sugiere el nombre de las clases que puedo utilizar.

Ahora al agregarlas con el Script.Render:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/BoostrapCSS") %>
```

no me funciona el intellisense y no muestra ninguna clase (uso boostrap en la solución).

Esto NO ME PASA con la solución que es MVC (C#), pero si con esta que es un Sitio Web de Visual Basic .NET.

¿Hay alguna configuración que agregar para que el intellisense funcione?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.
Saludos.

Comment: solo como referencia, podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]? Tu pregunta esta bien estructurada y es muy clara. Bienvenido!!

Comment: Gracias. Me interiorizaré sobre estos temas, para ser claro a la hora de formular mis consultas y poder resolver mis inconvenientes. Saludos.